# Active record Query for has many through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through

I have a has_many through relationship in my rails app and its associated as follows:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :car_fuel_types
     has_many :fuel_types , through: :car_fuel_types 
end

class FuelType < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :car_fuel_types
    has_many :cars , through: :car_fuel_types
end

class CarFuelType < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :fuel_type
    belongs_to :car
end
```

In my app the user selects a fuel_type and on the basis of the selected fuel_type I have to filter the cars.

So, in the cars controller I have the fuel_type_id that is passed as a parameter by the user and now I need to select the cars corresponding to that fuel_type.

Can anybody help me in writing a active record query to do this ?

EDIT 1:

Incorporating the answer below,

I am using the following code in the index action of my cars controller:

```
def index   
  @cars= FuelType.find(params[:fuel_type_id]).cars

respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json { render json: @cars }
end
```

end

I am using the following curl command to test it

```
 curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json"  -H "X-User-Email: $EMAIL" -H "X-User-Token: $TOKEN" -X GET http://localhost:3000/cars.json\?id\=4
```

This is the query that is getting executed

```
  SELECT  "fuel_types".* FROM "fuel_types" WHERE "fuel_types"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 4]]

  Car Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "cars".* FROM "cars" INNER JOIN "car_fuel_types" ON "cars"."id" = "car_fuel_types"."car_id" WHERE "car_fuel_types"."fuel_type_id" = $1  [["fuel_type_id", 4]]

  Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 85ms (ActiveRecord: 17.0ms)

   NoMethodError - undefined method `fuel_type_id' for #<Car:0x007f273923eb70>:
```

Can anybody help me figure out why is this error happening ?

Comment: I think the problem might by within your migrations/table structure. Could you provide your schema.rb?

Comment: create_table "car_fuel_types", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "car_id"
    t.integer  "fuel_type_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
  end

  create_table "car_models", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "engine_displacement"
    t.integer  "car_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",          null: false
  end

  create_table "cars", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should probably return what you need:

```
FuelType.find(fuel_type_id).cars
```

Comment: This is working fine when in rails console, but when I try to write a the same query in the index function of cars controller by writing the query 
**@cars= FuelType.find('id= ?', params[:fuel_type_id]).cars** 
It is giving me this error **Couldn't find all FuelTypes with 'id': (id= ?, 4) (found 1 results, but was looking for 2)**  . Can you please help

Comment: Try it like this `@cars = FuelType.find(params[:fuel_type_id]).cars`. You only need the id. See also here how it works: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find

Comment: Now it is giving this error ** undefined method `fuel_type_id' for #<Car:0x007f2737871bc0>**

Comment: Please show the error stacktrace and the exact command you were using.

Comment: I am using this curl command to test it **curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json"  -H "X-User-Email: $EMAIL" -H "X-User-Token: $TOKEN" -X GET http://localhost:3000/cars.json\?fuel_type_id\=4**
and getting the following error trace  **undefined method `fuel_type_id' for #<Car:0x007f2739962a78>** and it is pointing to this command in my respond_to block  **format.json { render json: @cars }**

Comment: And your `@cars` assignment is the one from my comment?

Comment: This is my @cars assignment **@cars= FuelType.find(params[:fuel_type_id]).cars**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91790/discussion-between-egonwilzer-and-lovish-choudhary).

Comment: The function as a whole is working, if I remove the respond to block from my controller Index action, I am using this render function because I need a root value in my json response, If I don't use this respond to block the function suggested by you is working

Comment: Maybe you should try to find help for this issue in another question, since this one covers the AR query, which was basically resolved.

Comment: I have posted a new question here **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33038828/adding-root-value-to-a-response-from-has-many-through-relationship** please take a look